# How to compile match expressions in ocaml

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml, abstract-syntax-tree, type-inference, transpiler

Im using printtyped.ml to transpile from ocaml to scala source code. I.e. I use the -dtypedtree flag and a modified typedtree printer to do source to source translation.

Now I'd like to translate to another language that doesnt have such advanced pattern matching capabilities as ocaml, in this case the Ceylon Language, but needs type information.

How can I compile Texp_match (the match expression expressed as typed abstract syntax tree) into its compiled form, again as a typed abstract syntax tree.

As far as I can see, compilation of match expression works on the lambda form not on the tast.

But I might be wrong. I hope so ...

Is there a function that compiles match expressions from tast to tast, so that I can print out the tast into a typed language without (advanced) pattern matching?

Comment: Have you tried the `-dlambda` flag? This is the compilation step where pattern-matching actually get processed.

Comment: Hmm. Other than my (very basic) knowledge of OCaml's compilation process, I won't be of great help here.

Comment: What makes a `switch` instruction *not* work?

Comment: @PatJ "What makes a switch instruction not work" ... in Ceylon? Ceylon cannot 1. match (and bind) against  variables, and 2. match against constants within one pattern. It can both (1. und 2.) within different patterns within one switch expression: ceylon cannot: match (1,2) with (a, 2) -> ...It can switch ([1,2])case([Integer a, Integer b]) ... case ([1,2]) ...

Comment: @PatJ  so in an outer switch I can destructure and match against (and bind) variables and then in an inner switch match against values. But this requires an extensive reorganisation when transpiling  from ocaml to ceylon. It would even be easier to pack the patterns in an TreeMap ... So, the switch statement of ceylon is practically of no use for this purpose of transpilation

Comment: @Michael if the pattern matching is not contained into your language, you will have to do that reorganisation yourself (have fun). The good news is, there is current work to add type information to the lambda representation which would make your work (and everyone's) easier. In the meantime, you are stuck with trying to recode `matching.ml`. 3k lines of code, a breeze! (I truly feel sorry for you)

Comment: @PatJ Where can I see this ongoing work to add type information to the lambda representation? Is it a fork? Is it a separate module ... part of bucklescript ... ? What is the current state of affairs?

Comment: @Michael unfortunately, that may take a lot of time. The first step, which is to only propagate function types is [here](https://github.com/ocaml/ocaml/pull/1029). There is also a fork with complete type propagation [here](https://github.com/OCamlPro-Couderc/ocaml/tree/propagate-trunk) though integration of that one seems postponed indefinitely.

Comment: @PatJ some news on complete type propagation?

Comment: @Michael Don't count on it. The project is quite dormant, not to say dead.